# I want to have 3 boxes across page with one specific post in each

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to have 3 boxes across my WP page.

```
<div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-md-4">
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<?php static $count = 0;
if ($count == "1") { break; }
else { ?>

<div class="post">
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
</div>

<?php $count++; } ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>                 
            </div>



        <div class="col-md-4">
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<?php static $count = 0;
if ($count == "1") { break; }
else { ?>

<div class="post">
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
</div>

<?php $count++; } ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>                 
            </div>



            <div class="col-md-4">
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<?php static $count = 0;
if ($count == "1") { break; }
else { ?>

<div class="post">
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
</div>

<?php $count++; } ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>                 
            </div>
        </div>
```

The object is to have one different specific post in each of the three boxes.

I am trying to make a page that has every block of text easily editable from the admin rather than the code. I am using a plugin that allows me to add a shortcode to a post where I want my specific post to show.

I have the boxes in place and have everything correct.

The first box populates with the correct post as it should but the other two won't display their posts.

It seems that maybe I can only use the loop once on the page, if so how can I achieve my aims?

Thanks for reading, any understandable advice will be very welcome, I have only recently started custom themes and PhP is a bit of a struggle too so I would be grateful if the help could be dumbed down a bit.

NB: I have tried replacing break with continue as suggested but the second and third post still don't show. Is it possible that there is more than just replacing the word break with continue?

Answer (score 0):

Your loop `breaks` out of the foreach loop on the second iteration since `$count = 1`. You might have wanted to do `continue` to skip the 2nd post?

(Don't be tempted to think that `break` just breaks out of the conditional block. The conditional logic simply chooses which path or block of code to execute.)

**EDIT**
First of all, you are doing a loop for each box...The purpose of the loop is so that you don't need to repeat your code. 
Second, you are restarting the loop each time..

Use the loop like this:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post' ) );
<?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="post">
    <?php the_title();
    the_content();
    ?>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
?>
```

There a couple ways to do the query. I do like the get_posts better for simple queries because you don't need to reset the postdata using that way. You'd pass in the same arguments to the `WP_Query`. 
Also I recommend you create a page template for this and assign it to a page. This way if you want to change your template you can just assign the page a different one instead of modifying your index.php code.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for trying to help. I have tried replacing break with continue but unless I need to edit the loop more than just adding continue it made no difference. I have edited my question to include the full code that I am struggling with and a fuller explanation

Comment: You need to tell me more. What file is this code written in? What's your query?

Comment: Hi, I am writing this code in my index.php. I want three feature boxes across the top under the jumbotron. Each box will have a title, Heating, Cooling, Service. Each of the boxes has a short description. I want the description to be editable via the backend rather than the html. I have a plugin that allows me to add the text into a post that shows in the plugin area. That post gives me a shortcode that I just paste into an ordinary blank post.

Comment: I want each of the three blank posts with different shortcodes to show in each of the 3 feature boxes, The first one showed as i expected but the other two didn't show at all even though the loop code was the same for each area as shown in my code. I agree that i used the same loop 3 times, it made sense to me as there were 3 distinct areas.

Comment: The code you suggest looks like an ordinary loop though I could be wrong of course, will it show just the 3 specific shortcodes in the three specific areas. Thank you for taking the time to explain my errors to me if I am still not making anything clear please let me know.

Comment: Your index.php in the root directory of your current theme? What is the post type? just the default WordPress posts? And how is the page made? What is the url? Template?

Comment: My index.php is in my custom theme (this theme). My post type is just an ordinary default post. The page is just an index, header.php, footer.php, functions, stylesheet etc. The site is on my localhost only.  I did find this, maybe this would work? `code` <?php
$post_id = 26;
$queried_post = get_post($post_id);
$title = $queried_post->post_title;
echo $title;
echo $queried_post->post_content;
`code`

Comment: Yea you need to set your query since the index.php sets it to your latest post I think (not too sure on that). See my edit.

Comment: Thank you for your help. `<?php
$post_id = 38;
$queried_post = get_post($post_id);
$title = $queried_post->post_title;
echo $title;
echo $queried_post->post_content;?>
`works!! - Now I just have to add an icon and style it all.